Short story or novella. Human colony on planet with intelligent aliens. Aliens, with permission, lay their eggs in living human beings
The humans and aliens have been cooperating in this way for several generations.
In the past before humans came to their planet, the aliens used to lay their eggs in animals, they would hatch and eat the animal flesh. This did not work well. In those days most of the alien young died.
In their current way of reproducing, the aliens lay eggs in volunteer humans. This is painful and unpleasant for the human, but only in very unusual circumstances is it fatal. The alien mother uses pheromones (I think) to ease the pain of the human being helping them reproduce.
I think the humans were a lost colony, no longer in contact with the rest of humanity.
A politically powerful female alien is pretty much adopted as part of the human family. She has known the mother since she was a small child. The alien acts like a kindly grandmother to the human children. Their mother keeps reminding them how powerful and influential their 'grandmother.' is. She insists they always speak to her with a great deal of politeness.
The alien gives the human family unfertilised eggs to eat. They are intoxicating and improve health and longevity. The human mother refuses most of her egg and gives it to her children. She seems to be feeling guilty about allowing her daughter to be a host for eggs.
The protagonist, a teenage girl in the family, volunteers to be implanted with the alien's eggs. She knows they will hatch out and eat her muscles but it is pretty much the only way their old family friend can reproduce. The attitude of the teenage girl seems to be, somebody has to do this unpleasant and somewhat dangerous task and I prefer it to be me and not any of my siblings.
They have a family friend, a human man who has had eggs laid in him by another female alien. The normal way it works is that when the eggs are hatching and eating their human host's muscles, the alien mother uses pheromones to prevent the human suffering excruciatingly pain. In the case of this man, something goes wrong. The young aliens are eating into him and their mother cannot be there. He keeps crying out the name of his alien friend who laid eggs in him. He trusted her to be there and ease his pain. She did really want to be there but could not, perhaps due to illness.
Their politically powerful alien 'family member ' talks about the current way of doing things. She says the system is far from perfect,but it could have been much worse. The powerful aliens could have made all the humans into slaves and sold the right to lay eggs in them to the highest bidder. The policy of linking human families with alien families and asking for volunteers is much better than what could have happened.
There are not enough volunteer humans, not enough humans in total for every alien who wants to lay eggs to do so. The protagonist remembers as a small child, she rode on her alien friend's shoulders in a public place. There were lots of envious stares from members of her own species. They would all have liked to have a human to lay their eggs.

Probably a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/243589/short-story-about-humans-serving-as-hosts-to-the-larval-stage-of-insects. The answer was Bloodchild by Octavia E. Butler

Yes it is Blood child. I am not sure how to close this as a duplicate.

Not sure how it works on the asker side, but from an answer side it's a matter of using the close vote.

At 3000 rep, you should have the privilege of casting a close vote. However, it seems the policy here on story ID questions is that they're only closed as dupes once the dupe has been answered and the answer accepted. :shrug:
